# PayPal All-In-One Payment Solution - Clone to multiple options in checkout process

Tags: checkout, magento2.2, payment-methods, paypal

***TLDR***; Clone **"PayPal All-In-One Payment Solution"** payment method to have **THREE** different payment options in **“Payment Method”** section of the checkout process.

---

Magento 2 comes with "PayPal All-In-One Payment Solution" that enables user to pay by PayPal but also by credit/debit card through the same payment method.

When this option is enabled, it shows only **ONE** payment option in the checkout process. This is understandable, however, I would like to offer more than one payment option in the checkout **"Payment Method"** section such as **"Credit Card"**, **"Debit Card"** and **"PayPal"** which all go to the same place.

In conclusion, my goal is to create two more radio buttons in the “Payment Method” section of the checkout that mimic "PayPal All-In-One Payment Solution" logic.

To visualise my goal:

**Current setup:**

```
PayPal Payment ---- [PayPal Method]
```

**Desired result:**

```
Credit Card ---
Debit Card  ----- [PayPal Method]
PayPal      ---
```

I don't even know where to start so any help or directions will be highly appreciated.

---

**EDIT:**

To clarify, I am using the "PayPal All-In-One Payment Solution - **Website Payments Standard**" which redirect customers to PayPal website to take the payment.

**EDIT2:**

To avoid further misunderstanding, I do not want to split the payment gateway and I do not want to create separate payment solutions. All I want to have, is “PayPal All-In-One Payment Solution - Website Payments Standard” enabled, however, display THREE options in the checkout step. These three buttons should do the same thing and redirect customer to PayPal. Whichever option is clicked, user gets the same result

Answer (score 0):

Some clarifications. **PayPal All-in-One Payment Solutions** it's just a name for configuration section in Admin Panel and it combines three PayPal integrations:

- **Payments Advanced**  - uses PayPal Payflow Pro payment gateway and provides a possibility to pay via credit/debit cards, Vault cards or PayPal Express Checkout (includes PayPal Credit)
- **Payments Pro** - uses PayPal Payflow Pro payment gateway and provides a possibility to pay via credit/debit cards, Vault cards or PayPal Express Checkout (includes PayPal Credit)
- **Payments Standard** - uses PayPal Express Checkout and has only a possibility to use Express Checkout or PayPal Credit

As you can see, the first two solutions just re-using Paflow Pro gateway and the last - PayPal Express Checkout.

So if you want to get an ability to use credit/debit cards and PayPal Express Checkout you can use Payflow Pro and you don't need to create three separate payment solutions.

Also, PayPal payment methods don't provide separate flow for debit or credit cards, so it doesn't make sense to separate them.

**UPD**: [The documentation](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/howdoi/checkout/checkout_payment.html) how to add a payment method on the Checkout step.

Comment: Hi @jonijones and thank you for you answer. I think, there is a misunderstanding. I do not want to split the payment gateway and I do not want to create separate payment solutions. All I want to have, is “PayPal All-In-One Payment Solution - Website Payments Standard” enabled, however, display THREE options in the checkout step. These three buttons should do the same thing and redirect customer to PayPal. Whichever option is clicked, user gets the same result.

Comment: When you need to create additional payment methods which will extend Payments Standard and provide needed customization.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure paypal express and credit/debit card method in single PayPal Express Checkout configuration. No need to configure seperatly.

**For enable credit and debit card options.**
Login to your paypal account and [Go to this paypal link.](https://www.paypal.com/merchantapps/appcenter/acceptpayments/checkout)

When you click on the link below and scroll down to the bottom of the page and you will see Advanced Integration click "Apply Now" this may take 2 business days to be approved, but they will send you an notification when it has been set up.

[image: Credit/Debit card enable]

That's it. Card method will enable within 2 days.